# How to add an element to a vector in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

Right now my code is looping through a text file and adding to a map the kgrams and characters that follow. The keys are strings and the values are vectors. But how do I add an element to the vector associated with the key?

Here is the code for adding that value, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wrapAround.length(); i++)
{
    temp = i + order;
    kgram[wrapAround.substr(i, temp)].add(temp++); //add value to the vector associated with key
}
```

I have an `if` statement later on to see if the values later on are in the map, and it never is true... I am not sure why.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: How does your `if` statement look like? Be aware that you add the value of `temp` before it is incremented. In fact your increment is superfluous.

Comment: vectors of _what_ exactly?

Comment: Assuming your vectors contain ints you should be able to replace `add` in your example with `push_back` and have it work, but it would be best for you to construct a short complete example with enough code to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: You know there's [documentation for this kind of stuff](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), right? If your map really does contain vectors, your code won't even compile as-written.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `string::substr` in C++ is length and not ending position.

Try accessing the k-gram like this instead: `wrapAround.substr(i, order)`

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the substring indexing up to you but to add items to a C++ vector you use `.push_back()` or `.push_front()`:

```
kgram[..].push_back(temp++);
```